# Can I write headers with the CsvProvider without providing a sample?

Tags: f#, f#-data

Why is it that if I create a new CSV type with the `CsvProvider<>` in F# like this:

```
type ThisCsv = CsvProvider<Schema = "A (decimal), B (string), C (decimal)", HasHeaders = false>
```

then create/fill/save the .csv, the resulting file does not contain the headers in the schema I specified? It seems like there should be a way to include headers in the final .csv file, but that's not the case.

Setting `HasHeaders = true` errors out, because there's no sample provided.  The only way for `HasHeaders = true` to work is to have a sample .csv.  It seems to me that there should be a way to specify the schema *without* a sample and also include the headers in the final file.

Am I missing something when I use `[nameOfMyCSV].Save()` that can include the headers from the schema or can this not be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm afraid the headers from the `Schema` are only used for the property names of the row. To have them in the file you save you have to provide `Sample`. Though, the sample can contain only the headers. Also, `HasHeaders` has to be set to `true`:

```
type ThisCsv = CsvProvider<
                Sample="A, B, C", 
                Schema = "A(decimal), B, C(decimal)", 
                HasHeaders = true>
```

If the sample contains only headers then if you want to specify data types the schema has to be provided as well.

You can see that the schema is used for property only when you rename the `Sample` headers in the `Schema`:

```
type ThisCsv = CsvProvider<
                Sample="A, B, C", 
                Schema = "A->AA(decimal), B->BB, C(decimal)", 
                HasHeaders = true>
```

Then the generated row will have properties like `AA`, `B`, `CC`. But the file generated will still have `A`, `B`, `C`. Also, the `Headers` property of a csv you created using this schema will be `Some [|"A"; "B"; "C"|]`:

```
// Run in F# Interactive
let myCsv = new ThisCsv([ThisCsv.Row(1.0m, "a", 2.0m)])
myCsv.Headers
// The last line returns: Some [|"A"; "B"; "C"|]
```

Also, to get better understanding of what's happening inside the parser worth taking a look at the source code in GitHub: [CSV folder](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/master/src/Csv) in general and [CsvRuntime.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Csv/CsvRuntime.fs) in particular.

Comment: Great explanation.  Thanks!